# Moving SQL Data into Azure SQL PaaS

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a database in the SQL Server installed on Azure VM. DB Size is 2 GB.

How and what is the best approach to move all data into Azure SQL PAAS Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the method posted by @Harris Xu is absolutely correct, I am adding the issues which I faced when I migrated my 500+ GB SQL Server DB from Azure VM to PaaS using .bacpac method.

Azure SQL DB is in a away limited when compared to On-prim SQL Server or SQL Server on VM's.

You will not face these issues while creating the .bacpac file but when you try to import, it might give some of the following compatibility issues.

1. **Master Keys , Symmetric Keys, Service Queues and certificates** cannot
   be migrated to cloud. Drop them before preparing bacpac.
2. Drop orphaned Users.
3. If you are using **XP_CMDSHELL, Trace Flags, DBCC commands or column store indexes**, you got to remove them too.
4. **Cross DB Queries are not allowed on Azure SQL DB**. Remove all occurrences of ..
5. If you are calling an API from your stored proc then that too is not possible in Azure SQL DB. As a workaround you can use [Logic Apps on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview#:%7E:text=Azure%20Logic%20Apps%20is%20a,%2Dbusiness%20(B2B)%20scenarios.).

Moreover, Microsoft Migration assistant can help you find compatibility issues before hand too. You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).

**NOTE : This no way the full list of issues**, I faced them because I was using all above features, if you are not using them you will not face them.

Comment: when importing the .bacpak does the import stops or these issues are just flagged?

Comment: @Francesco Mantovani, The import will abort.

Answer (score 1):

## SQL Migration using data-tier application export/import (BACPAC)

The BACPAC file encapsulates the database schema as well as the data stored in a database application that can be simple imported to an Azure SQL Database.
Workloads using the source database need to be taken offline during the export process to ensure that the exported BACPAC file contains all data in a complete and consistent state.

### Export to bacpac file in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

You can follow this [post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-azure-sql-server/).

1. Open and connect database file in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
   [image]
2. To export a database file, right click on the name of the database. In the context menu, select Tasks > Export Data-tier Application.
   [image]
3. The option will open the wizard. Click Next> Introduction page and go to the Export Settings.
   [image]

### Import a bacpac file to Azure SQL

1. After you connect to your Azure sql, go to Object Explorer pane, right click the database, and select Import Data-tier.
   [image]
2. The option will open the wizard. Click Next> Introduction page and go to the Import Settings.
   [image]
3. The Import settings are requested to the bacpac file to import.
   [image]